# Erlang: How to make an alias from 'erl_script_alias' to root url?

Tags: erlang, alias, inets

Here is the *inets* configuration file that I have:

```
[{port, 443}, 
 {server_name, "example.com"},
 {server_root, "./root/"},
 {document_root, "./htdocs/"},
 {socket_type, {essl, [{certfile, "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem"}, {keyfile, "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem"}]}},
 {directory_index, ["index.html"]},
 {erl_script_alias, {"/erl",[functions]}},
 {erl_script_nocache, true},
 {script_alias, {"/cgi-bin/", "/home/example/site/cgi-bin/"}},
 {script_nocache,true}
].
```

With this configuration file I can access:

```
https://example.com/cgi-bin/something.cgi

and

https://example.com/erl/functions/function
```

I already know that changing **{script_alias, {"/cgi-bin/"...** to **{script_alias, {"/"...** gives me access to cgi script from `https://example.com/`, but how can I get the same behavior with **erl_script_alias**? Ex.: accessing `https://example.com/` and getting access to `/erl/functions/function`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answering my own question:**

The solution that I found was to create a module to deal with "GET" requests of "/".

```
-module(mod_index).
-export([do/1]).
-include_lib("inets/include/httpd.hrl").

do(ModData) ->
    root_url(ModData#mod.method, ModData#mod.request_uri, ModData#mod.data).

root_url("GET", "/", _) ->
    {proceed, [{response, {200,"Content-Type: text/html\r\n\r\nSomething"}}]};

root_url(_, _, OldData) ->
    {proceed, OldData}.
```

And adding the module into the configuration file with the default modules:

```
[{port, 443}, 
 {server_name, "example.com"},
 {server_root, "./root/"},
 {document_root, "./htdocs/"},
 {socket_type, {essl, [{certfile, "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem"}, {keyfile, "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem"}]}},
 {directory_index, ["index.html"]},
 {erl_script_alias, {"/erl",[functions]}},
 {erl_script_nocache, true},
 {script_alias, {"/cgi-bin/", "/home/example/site/cgi-bin/"}},
 {script_nocache,true},
 {modules, [mod_index, mod_alias, mod_auth, mod_esi, mod_actions, mod_cgi, mod_dir, mod_get, mod_head, mod_log, mod_disk_log]}
].
```

As the documentation says, the modules' order matters.